# I'm trying to install my public key manually w/ scp

Tags: ssh, scp, key-authentication

I'm following a tutorial and it's going along well. I used ssh to connect fine. Then I created a private and public key. Which leads me to my first question it says that the keys have been saved to

> Your identification has been saved in /home/localuser/.ssh/id_dsa.
>
> Your public key has been saved in /home/localuser/.ssh/id_dsa.pub.

But when I look in that folder I don't see the *.ssh* folder. Is this done for security reasons and it's supposed to be hidden?

Next the tutorial instructs to manually copy the public key to the remote machine using this command:

> scp ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub username@mywebpage.com:.ssh/authorized_keys

When I run that command I get this response.

> ssh: connect to host mywebpage.com port 22: Connection refused lost
> connection

So, like I do when I first connected by ssh, I add *-p 2222* at the end of *scp* command. I then get this response:

> 2222: No such file or directory

I've also tried uppercase *-P 2222*

What am I doing wrong?

PS I'm using Linux Mint 15 and Cinnamon

**EDIT**

OK. Adding `-p 2222` right after `ssh` worked. However I've ran into another issue.

It then transferred the file. However I had to create the directory myself before it would transfer. Now it's supposed to ask my for my passphrase instead of my password. It didn't do this so then the tutorial said to run these commands. `chmod 700 ~/.ssh` & `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`. But when I login it still asks for my password and not my passphrase.

Why is it not working?

**EDIT: I ran `ssh` with `-v` these are the mentions of `public key`:**

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering DSA public key: /home/localusername/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /home/localusername/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/localusername/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
```

I'll note this is prior to logging in.

Comment: Your intial question is solved; please accept the answer that was most helpful and then search for a similar question for your edit. If one doesn't already exist, open one. Please don't keep editing new (even if seemingly related) questions into this one.

Comment: Try running `ssh` with `-v` or even `-vv` to get more verbose output.  There should be some text in the output about an attempt to use your public key, and then there will be an explanation as to why it didn't work.  You could then add that into your post.

Comment: @dg99 OK. I've done that. You can take a look.

Comment: You're looking for any error messages that explain why the `id_rsa` attempt failed.  If there's no text there, you should try `ssh -vv` and then `ssh -vvv` if necessary.  Also, you should definitely take the advice @jasonwryan gave to heart and start an entirely new question lest this one get closed for breaking the rules.

Comment: @Ok. I'm going to start a new thread. But is there a way I can search for the `id_rsa` text so I don't have to read countless lines?

Comment: @jasonwryan Should I delete the edits I made so only the original question is there?

Comment: Yes, please remove the edits as they really are a new question. You don't need to search on `id_rsa`; just look at your settings in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `-P 2222` immediately after `scp` before the location parameters

```
scp -P 2222 ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub username@mywebpage.com:.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: @X Tian That worked to get my 1 step further. Thanks.

Comment: It then transferred the file. However I had to create the directory myself before it would transfer. Now it's supposed to ask my for my passphrase instead of my password. It didn't do this so they tutorial said to run these commands. `chmod 700 ~/.ssh`
`chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`. But when I login it still asks for my password and not my passphrase. What can the problem be? And also I still can't find the **.ssh folder**, is it supposed to be hidden?

Comment: I think this can also be done using the command `ssh-copy-id` that's often bundled on Linux systems.

Answer (score 1):

> But when I look in that folder I don't see the .ssh folder. Is this done for security reasons and it's supposed to be hidden?

In *nix, directories and files whose names start with a `.` are typically hidden by default from the user. You can see them with `ls` by doing `ls -a`.

Try, putting the `-P 2222` before the files on the command line. You must use a capital P, i.e., `-P` — lowercase `p` is used for something else. See `man scp`.

`scp` uses `ssh` to do the data transfer securely, which is why you need to specify the SSH port (since you're running it on a non-standard port).

Comment: lower-case `p` is used for `ssh`, no? Could you please take a look at my **edit** to my original question? I'm a bit stuck again.

Comment: Yes, for `ssh`, `-p` is for port. However, in `scp`, `-P` is the port. `-p`, in `scp`, is "Preserves modification times, access times, and modes from the original file."